# Why does ABAP cut string to one character?

Tags: abap

I have this simple ABAP code:

```
  data foo_string.
  foo_string = |hello world { sy-uname }|.
  MESSAGE |foo: { foo_string } :-)| TYPE 'E'.
```

Result:

```
foo: h :-)
```

Why was the string cut to one character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in this line:

wrong:

```
data foo_string.
```

correct:

```
data foo_string type string.
```

Comment: To say things explicitly, a declaration without an explicit type means **one character**.

Comment: Impressive that this compiles. So the default type for _anything_ is `TYPE c`, which is a synonym for `TYPE c LENGTH 1`. Who would've guessed?

Comment: @Florian this was driving my crazy for some minutes. I really could not understand what was going on, and why my string was cut to the first character. After roughly twenty minutes I found it and could laugh. Nevertheless backward compatibility is important. But sometimes it is healthy to remove old features. It seems to me that SAP avoids to deprecate and actually remove things.

Comment: Note that the type will be correctly deduced with inline declarations `data(foo_string) = |hello world { sy-uname }|` (string), `data(foo_string) = 'hello world'` (11 characters, because of straight quotes), ``data(foo_string) = `hello world` `` (string, because of inverted quotes). Funny fact: did you know that if an optional parameter is of type `any`, and is not passed, it will be of type `one character` (or table with lines of one character if it's an obsolete TABLES parameter).

Comment: @SandraRossi No, I did not know it before. But thank you for the hint (`data(foo_string) = |hello world { sy-uname }|`) that's short and clear.